# Angular submit outside form

Tags: angular, typescript, formgroups

I need to invoke `submit` on form(s) when clicking on button outside the form as well as changing `FormGroupDirective.submitted` to `true`.

I have next layout

```
<form (ngSubmit)="submit()" #myForm [formGroup]="formGroup">
...
</form>

<button (click)="formGroupDirective.ngSubmit.emit()" *ngIf="showEditControl"
    class="btn btn_blue mr-3 button-save" type="submit">
    {{'buttons.save' | translate}}
</button>
```

And component.ts

```
@ViewChild('myForm', {read: FormGroupDirective}) formGroupDirective: FormGroupDirective;
```

This does invoke `(ngSumit)` however the property `submitted` is not changed. It's not good to change the property itself as `submitted` is `readonly`. What could be done here (except for creating hidden submit buttons and emulating click on them)?

Answer (score 0):

use this.

in html:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" #myForm="ngForm">
    // ...Form Controls
</form>

<button (click)="submitForm()" *ngIf="showEditControl" class="btn btn_blue mr-3 button-save" type="submit">
    {{'buttons.save' | translate}}
</button>
```

and in component.ts

```
@ViewChild('myForm') form: FormGroupDirective;

formGroup: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    myInput: new FormControl(''),
    //etc...
});

submitForm() {
    this.form.onSubmit(undefined);
}
```

Comment: I tried. That doesn't change the `submitted` property